# Versioning does not increment automatically

Tags: git, scala, sbt, sbt-git

I am using https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git to get the benefit of automatic versioning as descript in the section **Versioning with Git**.

My `build.sbt` file looks as the following:

```
version := "0.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-encoding", "UTF-8", // source files are in UTF-8
  "-deprecation", // warn about use of deprecated APIs
  "-unchecked", // warn about unchecked type parameters
  "-feature", // warn about misused language features
  "-language:higherKinds", // allow higher kinded types without `import scala.language.higherKinds`
  "-Xlint", // enable handy linter warnings
  "-Xfatal-warnings", // turn compiler warnings into errors
  "-Ypartial-unification" // allow the compiler to unify type constructors of different arities
)

scalacOptions in(Compile, console) ~= {
  _.filterNot(Set("-Xlint"))
}

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.6.0",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.2"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0" % "test",
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.6" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.6" % "test"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.5.22",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
)

libraryDependencies += "com.dimafeng" %% "testcontainers-scala" % "0.25.0" % "test"


enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
enablePlugins(GitVersioning)
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8080)
git.formattedShaVersion := git.gitHeadCommit.value map { sha =>
  s"$sha".substring(0, 7)
}

dockerUpdateLatest := true
dockerAlias := DockerAlias(None, Some("zerocoder"), (packageName in Docker).value, git.gitDescribedVersion.value)
```

After the commit, it does not increment from version "0.1.0" to "0.2.0" automatically.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is:

1. Remove / leave out the explicit setting version from your `build.sbt` file (i.e this statement `version := "0.1.0"`)
2. Create a git tag to set the desired version (prefixed by v), see the [doc](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git#versioning-with-git), for instance

```
>git tag -a v0.2.0  -m "my version 0.2.0"
```

You can then see the version set by the plugin, by running:

```
>sbt version
// Displays
// [info] 0.2.0
```

Here is a bit of explanation:

So the way `sbt-git` works, is that it sets the version of your sbt build for you (the one that you get as a result of a running `sbt version`). To do so, it follows several [rules](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git#versioning-with-git), here are the 2 first:

> 1. Looks at version-property setting (default to project.version), and checks the sys.props to see if this has a value. If so, use it.
> 2. Otherwise, looks at the project tags. The first to match the gitTagToVersionNumberSetting is used to assign the version. The default is to look for tags that begin with v and a number, and use the number as the version. If there are multiple version tags, it will pick the highest.

So in your case, because you set explicitly the `project version` to `0.1.0` in your `build.sbt`, what you would get as a result of running `sbt version` is `0.1.0`. Even after doing some commits the value of `sbt version` would still be `0.1.0` because the rules one would apply (as long as the version is set in your `build.sbt`). **Note that the plugin doesn't change the value set in that file**, it only uses it, when it's defined.

If you were to **remove that line** (`version := "0.1.0"`), then rule 2 would apply, which in a nutshell look up the `tag` and return the first one to match `gitTagToVersionNumberSetting` which by default is a string that begin with `v` and followed by a number.

So essentially to get your project set to version `0.2.0` using the plugin, you would have to create a tag on top of the head commit `v0.2.0`, (running `git tag -a v0.2.0  -m "my version 0.2.0"`, for instance).

And as you develop your project, several commits would be added, leading up to your version `0.3.0` (or `0.2.1`), and once you create the corresponding tag on top of the latest commit - let's say the tag `v0.3.0` - then the `plugin` would pick that up (applying the rule 2) and use it to set it as version of your project (that you could see by running `sbt version`, as said previously).

This is a flow you would use basically to make your project version follow you your (git) `tags` version.

Comment: So the idea here is that instead of the plugin updating the version specified in your `build.sbt`, there is no version specified there at all. Instead, the plugin calculates the version (on the fly, at the start of each build) by looking at your git status.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, when I commit it, then it will calculate the version automatically?

Comment: What I mean is, for example, the current tag is `v0.2.0`. Then I make some code changes, commit it, then what I expect is, that the tag gets increase to `0.3.0` automatically.

Comment: @zero_coding, basically it's for you to create a tag on top of your commit and the plugin will use it to set the version your project

Comment: Great Stuff :)!